# Limit int field in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I have an interger field that I want my users to only be able to pick between the numbers 1 and 10.  So currently I am using the Range attribute in the model:

```
[Range(1, 10)]
public int NumberOfExtensions { get; set; }
```

However, I want to prevent the view from allowing the number to go below 1 and above 10.  This to me would be a better user experience.

Here is my view code:

```
</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfExtensions)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumberOfExtensions)
      </div>
</div>
```

Brroshan below recommended I use Javascript. This is a little closer to what I want.  I am now trying to modify it so the numbers will not go outside the desired range.  This is what I tried and it does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $("#@Html.IdFor(s => s.NumberOfExtensions)").on("input", function () 
            {
                if ($(this).val() < 1)  
                {
                    $(this).val() = 1
                }
                else if ($(this).val() > 10)
                {
                    $(this).val() = 10
                } 
            });

        });

    </script>
```

I want it to stop at the #1 and at the #10 - not give an error.

Comment: Change `$(this).val() = 1` to `$(this).val(1);` and `.val(10)` then you're set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript/jQuery to controll the minimum and maximum allowed value of the element.

Try this:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfExtensions)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumberOfExtensions)
</div>

@section scripts{
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#@Html.IdFor(s => s.NumberOfExtensions)")
        .on("input",function () {

            if ($(this).val() < 0 || $(this).val() > 10) {
                alert("Cannot be less than 0 or more than 10");
                $(this).val("");
            }
        });

    });

 </script>

}
```

Comment: brroshan, I have not used any javascript in my projects before.  Would I replace my field with that? or put this in the script section in the bottom? or something completely different?

Comment: It goes inside `@section scripts { }` if you've got `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` in your `_Layout.cshtml` inside the shared folder of your `Views` folder

Comment: ty brroshan.  That is almost what I need.  I updated my original question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

you can use attributes html

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfExtensions, new {min= 5, max = 10})
```